# Javascript clock on new tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I'm new here so if you see anything off about my question or 'etiquette' please let me know!

I'm trying to create a personalized new tab extension in Google Chrome, and have a problem with JavaScript time code appearing. Though it works in Brackets, the compiler I use, the time never displays whenever I load the extension folder onto Chrome. After searching around, I learned that this was because I had my Javascript inline rather than in an external file, and so I naturally attempted to move my script into a time.js file. I am not totally sure about how to show the time upon the new tab loading, but I thought I'd show y'all my attempts.

My index.html file, disregarding irrelevant code, shows as:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>New Tab</title>
    <script type = "text/javascript" src = "time.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload = "startTime()">
    <div id = "time"></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

^ Can't see closing html tag for some reason. Anyway, here is my time.js file, using some changed up w3school code:

```
function startTime() {
    var today = new Date();
    var h = today.getHours();
    var m = today.getMinutes();
    h = minusTwelve(h);
    m = checkTime(m);
    document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =
    h + ":" + m;
    var t = setTimeout(startTime, 500);} 
function minusTwelve(i) {
if (i > 12) {i = i - 12};
if (i == 0) {i = 12};
return i;

function minusTwelve(i) {
if (i > 12) {i = i - 12};
if (i == 0) {i = 12};
return i;}

function checkTime(i) {
if (i < 10) {i = "0" + i};
return i;}
```

(sorry about the indents in those last two functions, something went weirdly :P)

Anyway, I have this so far and I am not sure how to integrate the time when the tab loads in Chrome. I have seen some people mention addEventListener or something for clicks and whatnot, but I am not sure how this would apply here. Also, in the body of my HTML is the onload call, and though I would think this would take care of it, it seems to not have :/. I would really appreciate your help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see any errors in the Javascript console?

Also one thing I noticed is that, you have missed the closing braces for your first function `minusTwelve()`

See if it fixes the issue

And have you mentioned your script file in the manifest file? [Check this docs](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the response. That is an error on my part, had trouble copying and pasting my code, and so there is only on minusTwelve() function in my code, and it works perfectly when not imported as an extension in Chrome. I didn't know about the content script, though! I added this into my manifest.json file:
    {... "content_scripts": [
    {
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "css": ["style.css"],
        "js": ["time.js"],
        "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ],
 ...
} to no avail. Any extra help would be very appreciated!

Comment: You should try debugging your code: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Comment: Hello again Akhilesh. Thanks for your responses! I have looked at the tutorial and went through the different breakpoints I'd placed, but it hasn't seemed to resolve the issue I've had with Javascript appearing. Is there any link to manifest.json I have to make in HTML that can resolve the issue? And do you perhaps know how if I have to implement my time.js in a different way, using event listeners or something of the sort? I really appreciate your responses, learned quite a bit haha.

Comment: There are plenty of tutorials available for chrome extension development. Maybe reading a few of them will give you some ideas: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/developing-google-chrome-extensions--net-33076